# read android headphone jack input signal

Tags: android, signal-processing, headphones

My question is the following.
I want to build an android app and use the android's headphone jack input mic to read voltages in the range 0V-2V and act accordingly for example if the voltage is 1.045 show a red circle on the screen if the voltage is 1.047 show a red circle and so on.
Can this be done?